What are the steps to establish an LTI 1.3 connection in Laravel using the laravel-celtic-lti library available on GitHub?
What are the steps to establish an LTI 1.3 connection in Laravel using the laravel-celtic-lti library available on GitHub?
I tried to make the connection using the example provided in the celtic-lti documentation for implementation, but when I attempted it, I received an error stating that the platform is not available.
